# Threads getting dropped from Queue when Executor Service with fixed thread pool is used with Kafka Listener

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, executorservice, executor

When I'm trying to use executorService (fixed thread pool of 50) with Kafka, some of threads are getting dropped from the Queue and are not getting processed.

For example, for below code : count of lines printed in logs: 
"Inside Kafka Listener" : 3000
"Processing message" : 2100
"Exception occurred" : 0

```
@Named
public class KafkaListener {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

    @Inject
    KafkaMessageProcessor kafkaMessageProcessor;

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "topicName",
            containerFactory = "filterKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(String message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside Kafka Listener " + message);
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println("Processing message");
                kafkaMessageProcessor.process(message);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred :" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the count of the lines in the logs to be equal as newFixedThreadPool uses Blocking Queue with size `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Do you experience any different behavior if you change `submit` to `execute`?

Comment: I tried execute too, the behavior is same.